# Chrome calculate wrong position top in dropdown with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Hello I faced with issue I cant solve long time. So please help me.
The thing is that I am trying to make dropdown (when hovering to the "cart (0)" with slide effect and using for this jquery. In firefox it is worked good? but Chrome calculate top position wrong. Here the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CYR74/)**
My part of the code:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="sign-up-list">
                        <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Log in</a></li>
                        <li class="cart">
                            <a href="#">cart <span>(0)</span></a>
                            <div class="drop-holder">
                                <div class="drop">
                                    <ul class="product-list">
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="img-holder"><img src="images/img-04.jpg" alt="product photo"/></div>
                                            <div class="text">
                                                <span class="product-name">Custom made Headboard</span>
                                                <span class="product-price">US$290.00</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="img-holder"><img src="images/img-05.jpg" alt="product photo"/></div>
                                            <div class="text">
                                                <span class="product-name">Antique Reclaimed Barnwoo...</span>
                                                <span class="product-price">US$75.00</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="total-viewer">
                                        <span class="title">Total:</span>
                                        <span class="total-price">US$365.00</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <a class="btn gray" href="#">View cart</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.sign-up-list {
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 12px 19px 0 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.sign-up-list>li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 7px 0 8px;
    background: url(../images/sep-01.png)  no-repeat 0 3px;
}
.sign-up-list>li:first-child {
    background: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.sign-up-list a {color: #474646;}
.sign-up-list a:hover {
    color: #03a4d9;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sign-up-list .cart {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 18px 34px;
}
.sign-up-list .cart:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 9px;
    background: url(../images/sprite.png)  no-repeat -52px -4px;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
}
.sign-up-list .cart a {
    color: #f27242;
    position: relative;
}
.sign-up-list .cart span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 0 0 3px;
}
.drop-slide-wrapper {z-index: 2;}
.sign-up-list .cart .drop-holder {
    border-top: 3px solid #585858;
    width: 322px;
    background: #e8e8e8;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
}
.sign-up-list .cart .drop {
    margin: -3px 0 0;
    background: url(../images/bg-black-drop.png)  no-repeat 14px 0;
    padding: 29px 18px 18px 18px;
}
.sign-up-list .product-list {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sign-up-list .product-list li {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 11px;
}
.sign-up-list .product-list .img-holder {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:0 8px 0 0;
    width: 83px;
}
.sign-up-list .product-list .text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 21px;
    text-transform: none;
    width: 190px;
}
.sign-up-list .product-list .product-name {display: block;}
.sign-up-list .product-list .product-price {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.sign-up-list .total-viewer {
    border-top: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
    padding: 14px 0;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}
.sign-up-list .total-viewer .title {
    width: 83px;
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 21px;
}
.sign-up-list .total-viewer .total-price {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 21px;
    color: #f27242;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 19px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #f27242;
    padding: 19px 10px 21px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}
.btn:hover {
    background: #585858;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn.gray {background: #585858;}
.sign-up-list .cart .btn {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
}
.btn.small {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 215px;
}
.btn.cross {
    padding: 0 43px 0 0;
    background:#f27242;
    position: relative;
}
.btn.cross:after {
    content:'';
    background: url(../images/sprite.png)  no-repeat -236px -145px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 15px;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
}
.btn.cross span {
    display: block;
    border-right: 1px solid #f19c7c;
    padding: 10px;
}
.btn.cross:active {background: #585858;}
.btn.cross:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #585858;
}
.btn.cross:hover span {border-color:#797979;}
```

Comment: seems to be an awefull lot of js just for this effect. Here is one way to do it with plain css: http://jsfiddle.net/CYR74/2/

Comment: @NicoO Sorry but I really need to do this with jquery. I am making website with deep browser support (also with compatibility of old mobile platforms) so there is a lot of jquery here. So the problem still exists